# Different 2D Convolution results between PyTorch and Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pytorch, convolution

I am trying to find the equivalent keras representation of the following PyTorch line:

```
conv1 = nn.Conv2d(int(filters*s), filters, kernel_size=(3, 1), stride=int(1/s), padding=(1, 0))
```

Here is the full code

```
import torch
from torch import nn

import torch
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from keras import initializers
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# constants between both libraries
filters = 2
s = 1

# Set the seed for reproducible set of numbers between keras and pytorch
torch.manual_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
tf.random.set_seed(0)

# Create a tensor in PyTorch of shape (128, 2, 1024, 1)
pytorch_tensor = torch.rand((128, 2, 1024, 1))

# Convert the PyTorch tensor to a NumPy array
numpy_array = pytorch_tensor.numpy()

# Reshape the NumPy array to the desired shape for Keras (128, 1024, 1, 2)
numpy_array = np.transpose(numpy_array, (0, 2, 3, 1))

# Create a tensor in Keras (TensorFlow) from the NumPy array
keras_tensor = tf.constant(numpy_array)

# PyTorch zeropad and convolution 
pytorch_conv1 = nn.Conv2d(int(filters*s), filters, kernel_size=(3, 1), stride=int(1/s), padding=(1, 0))(pytorch_tensor)

print(f"Pytorch values: {pytorch_conv1}")

# Keras zeropad and convolution 
keras_zeropad = layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,0),(1,0)))(keras_tensor)
keras_conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=(3, 1), strides=int(1/s), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last')(keras_zeropad)

print(f"Keras tensor values: {keras_conv1}")
```

I thought the issue was padding since PyTorch and Keras handle it differently. Namely, inside Keras’ `Conv2D` layer the padding can only be set to `valid` or `same`. Instead I am using the `ZeroPadding2D` layer before the `Conv2D` so asymmetric padding can be done in Keras. However, despite this I still cannot get the output data to match.

I wrote the following code which generates the same input tensor for PyTorch and Keras so I know the data is the same. I’ve also tried initializing the weights and bias's the same way but the data still doesn’t match.

I’ve seen posts about using the PyTorch weights in Keras to achieve the same results but I would like to avoid that for my application.

**Update:**
Changing the Keras Conv2D layer to the following still produces vastly different results compared to PyTorch. The padding and shape are equal, however Keras produces new data every time. I’ve looked into kernel initializers but nothing has produced data that matches PyTorch.

```
keras_zeropad = layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,0))(keras_tensor)
keras_conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=(3, 1), strides=int(1/s), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last')(keras_zeropad)

print(f"Keras tensor values: {keras_conv1}")
print(f"Keras tensor shape: {keras_conv1.shape}")
```

For readability the input tensor shape was changed to (1,2,4,1). Here is the PyTorch and Keras data that should match.

```
Pytorch values: tensor([[[[-0.1842],
          [-0.2021],
          [-0.3707],
          [-0.2296]],

         [[ 0.2727],
          [ 0.0941],
          [ 0.0927],
          [ 0.1981]]]], grad_fn=<ConvolutionBackward0>)
PyTorch tensor shape: torch.Size([1, 2, 4, 1])
Keras tensor values: [[[[-0.57757664  0.40883008]]

  [[ 0.21837917  0.6590299 ]]

  [[ 0.28047863  0.3622663 ]]

  [[ 0.2800742   0.2882987 ]]]]
Keras tensor shape: (1, 4, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a horizontal kernel size of `3` and want the same behavior as `padding='same'`, the padding set manually must be symmetrical and equal to `1` on both ends:

```
pad = layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,0))

conv = layers.Conv2D(filters, 
                     kernel_size=(3, 1), 
                     strides=int(1/s), 
                     padding='valid', 
                     data_format='channels_last')
```

Then `conv(pad(keras_tensor))` will have a shape of `(128, 1024, 1, 2)`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but this does not answer my question. I am struggling to have PyTorch and Keras produce matching convolution results despite the input parameters being equal. Please see my updated question.

Comment: How do you expect to get identical results if the convolutions are initialized differently? The layer you initialize in PyTorch won't have the same weights as that of Keras.

Comment: Not only do the weights get initialized randomly, but TensorFlow uses `glorot_uniform` for the weights, and `zeros` for the bias, while PyTorch seems to use `kaiming_uniform` for the weights and biases. So the randomly initialized weights are even sampled from different distributions. Of course they would produce different results with the same input.

Comment: @mhenning Even after setting the Keras initializers to kernel_initializer=‘he_uniform’ and bias_initializer=‘he_uniform’ my Keras layer still differs from PyTorch. Why is this? Feel free to write an answer with an example and I’ll accept it if you can show me what initializers are needed so the outputs match.

Comment: You still give *distributions* to sample from *randomly*. Sample 2 times from `he_uniform`, and you get 2 different set of weights. You can fix this with a seed, but I don't think there is the same seed for PyTorch and Tensorflow. Your best option is to initialize the weights in one library, then copy them to the layers of the other one.